# How can I create a relative PHP DateTime for the next instance of a particular time?

Tags: php, datetime

So it seems like the [PHP DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) allows you to use simple relative language strings such a `next Monday 12:00` to create objects associated with relative dates.

#### The Problem

The use case I'd like to achieve is to omit the day ("Monday") from the above string, and create a `DateTime` object **for the next instance of `06:00`**.

This presents a challenge because the code may be running at `07:00`, in which case the string `06:00` will return a date which is in the past, whereas if we run the code at `05:00` (or anytime before `06:00`), we will get the correct result.

*Note:* As an addendum, I don't want to have to do a bunch of complicated arithmetic and want to leverage the `DateTime` class to its fullest to keep myself from any sneaky little TimeZone or leap year issues.

#### My Question

How can I use the PHP DateTime class to obtain a DateTime object for the next instance of a certain time (without supplying the day as well)?

Comment: Yeah, I get that this is a Q&A site, though SO also offers the ability to answer your own questions for the benefit of others searching for solutions not clear on the documentation.   I don't see a problem with having more answered questions in one place for people searching for answers.

If I had asked the question without the answer (despite knowing the answer), would it have been more appropriate for SO in your eyes?

Comment: If you'd worded it as "I'm having this issue while trying to do X, here's teh codez" and self answered - it'd probably be better received than it is right now

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following -- is my question unclear or do you feel that others will not be able to understand the use case I was trying to achieve?  
 "I'm having this issue while trying to do X, here's teh codez" seems like exactly what I have provided here, it's just more embellished to help others understand the solution in the future.

Comment: You've laid out a base issue - but you've not followed proper Q&A in your Q part - it's more like an FAQ going "here's an issue, see below to guide through it" rather than a Q: "How do I fix this? The code is below" & A: "Here's the solution"

Comment: @Squagem: Self-answering is explicitly encouraged and is not by itself something that you needs addressing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. And Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) *are* questions. What has frequency have to do with it being on-topic? If this a FAQ there *could* be duplicate post on the site already, of course.

Comment: @SomeRandomPerson -- thanks again for trying to help me understand.  Despite the post title being a question itself, I'll add a simple question at the end of my post to make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the clarification.  I was certain that I was well within the guidelines when posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Solution

Here's how I ended up solving this...

```
/*
 * Simple function that returns a DateTime object representing the next instance of the time
 * supplied by the $timeString parameter.  
 *
 * $timeString: A string representing the time you wish to process, in 24h notation (i.e. 
 * '06:00' for 6:00am).
 */
function getNextTimeInstance($timeString){

  // First, grab an instance of the current moment as a DateTime object ('now' is optional).
  $rightNow = new DateTime('now');

  // Basic initializations for the object we want to use.
  $processedTime = new DateTime();

  // Change the Timezone if you need to do so.
  $processedTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Johannesburg'));

  // Set the time for our working DateTime to the time we want (i.e. '06:00').
  $processedTime->modify($timeString);

  // If the next instance of this time we're trying to process is in the past 
  // (meaning it is "less than" the current moment).
  if($rightNow > $processedTime){

    // Simply add one day to our working DateTime object. 
    $processedTime->modify('+1 day');
  }

  // Return the DateTime objects that represents the next instance of that time.
  return $processedTime;
}
```

I relied heavily on the following documentation to reach this result:

- The PHP [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).
- The [list of date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) that the PHP DateTime class will accept as inputs.
- The [list of supported TimeZone strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) that PHP will accept.

---

I hope this helps anyone else stuck in the same situation as myself, and if anyone else has a more elegant solution, please feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I created a PHP extension for the DateTime API called dt. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt). Using it for this task is very simple. Some Examples:

```
$dt = dt::create("today 06:00");
if($dt->isPast()) {
  $dt->modify("+ 1Day");
}
echo $dt;
```

Optionally, you can always set a time zone as the second parameter.

```
$time = "06:00";
$dt = dt::create("today $time","Africa/Johannesburg"); 
//:
```

The class works with special chains which can contain conditions. This allows you to create an expression that does the job with the create method alone.

```
$dt = dt::create("today 6:00|{{?YmdHis<NOW}}+1 Day");
```

The class also works with cron expressions.

```
$cron = "0 6 * * 1-5";//every Mo-Fr at 6:00
$dt = dt::create('now')->nextCron($cron);
```

Always delivers the next time 6:00 for Monday to Friday. At the weekend, the next time is Monday 6:00.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this mate.  I'm going to mark my answer as complete for now because it doesn't require any external libraries, though I'm sure many many people will appreciate this option as well!